# How do I calculate the time difference using Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to know the difference of time (hh:mm:ss) between two times.

For example:
Job start at 11:30pm at night but ends at 10:37 the next morning.

Comment: This might give you idea ... https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/calculate-the-difference-between-two-times-HP003056108.aspx

Comment: @Sathya Not sure it's a dupe. This question implies mOOse is using a date format for the start/end cells. The other question is using a custom format, or maybe just a number format (that doesn't span more than 24 hours). So given the link JackLock provided the answer could be something like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/A8lt9.png

Comment: @louis, the second answer on the duplicate thread should do what the OP wants.

Comment: @terdon I think those answers only work for things that happen on the same day.

Comment: @Louis In this example it *will* display 11:00. If the time is over 24 hours then make sure the cell formatting is d:h:mm to show count of days:hours:minutes. (edit: I misread -- thought Louis' comment was referring to JackLock's link.)

Answer (score 0):

A day has 24 hours.  Now add 24:00 for the next day time.  You need to update the next morning time as 34:37 (24:00 + 10:37).  The cell still displays the time as 10:37 but you get the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you give the start and end time cells a date format like [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTayz.png), you can calculate the time spent with `=TEXT(endTime-startTime, "h:mm:ss")`.

Example:
[image: Ex A]